# Is it possible to use a table data in the Outline Example?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

This is possible:

```
Scenario Outline: Add two numbers
Given I have entered <num1> and <num2> into the calculator
When I press add
Then the result should be <result> on the screen
Examples: 
| num1 | num2 | result |
| 50   | 70   | 120    |
| 10   | 20   | 30     |
```

My question is:

Is it possible to use a table into the Outline Example? Like the following scenario:

```
Scenario Outline: Add two numbers
Given I have entered <num1> and <num2> into the calculator
When I press add
Then the result should be <result> on the screen
| a  | b  | c   |
| 50 | 70 | 120 |
| 10 | 20 | 30  |  
Examples: 
| num1 | num2 | result |
| a    | b    | c      |
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible. for example

```
Scenario Outline: filing data
  Given I am on the home page
  And I <action>
  And "<field>" field loses focus
  Then I should see "<error>"
  Examples:
  | action                               | field | error              |
  | fill in "Email" with "test.test.com" | email | Email is not valid |
```